# Locating a data file installed by another Python library not working when installed to site-packages without "-e"

Tags: python

I have a project packaged as:

```
wcnlp-tools (project root)
  
 nlu-spacy
   setup.py
   ... 
   spacy(package name)
    ...

 nlu-wcnlp
   setup.py
   ... 
   wcnlp (package name)
     ...
```

wcnlp depends on spacy.

When I use:

```
pip install -e .
```

to install both libraries, it works all fine. However, if I don't use -e to install both, it reprots an error.

```
pip install .
```

The line which caused this error is:

```
abspath = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
read_yaml_file('os.path.join(abspath,"../../../../nlu-wcnlp/wcnlp/configs/spacy_config.yml")')
```

The error message is:

```
No such file or directory: '/Users/minmin/nlp/test/wcnlp-tools/ven/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spacy/lang/en/../../../../nlu-wcnlp/wcnlp/configs/spacy_config.yml'
```

The actual path, if correctly resolved, should be:

```
/Users/minmin/nlp/test/wcnlp-tools/ven/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spacy/lang/en/../../../../site-packages/wcnlp/configs/spacy_config.yml
```

So the differences between the two:

```
    site-packages

VS
    nlu-wcnlp
```

What's possible reason? Should I change my file path code, or setup scripts? Note that 'pip install -e .' works all fine.

ADDITIONS:
The error originates from nlu-wcnlp, but it's traced to the project nlu-spacy, which contains the error.

Error trace:

```
File "/Users/minmin/nlp/test/wcnlp-tools/ven/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wcnlp/nlp_utils.py", line 4, in <module>
    from spacy.lang.en.stop_words import STOP_WORDS
  File "/Users/minmin/nlp/test/wcnlp-tools/ven/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spacy/lang/en/__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
    CONFIG = read_yaml_file(SPACY_CONFIG_FILE)
  File "/Users/minmin/nlp/test/wcnlp-tools/ven/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wcnlp/utils/fileio.py", line 10, in read_yaml_file
    with open(filename) as stream:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/minmin/nlp/test/wcnlp-tools/ven/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spacy/lang/en/../../../../wcnlp-tools/wcnlp/configs/spacy_config.yml
```

Comment: Which project contains the line that causes the error; which file is it in relative to the project root? (Either way, that style of path is very much a code smell).

Comment: ...code that wants to find something packaged _with that same project_ should use its own `__file__`, but code that wants to find something packaged _inside a different project_ should use `otherproject.__file__` as the location they search relative to; no `../../../` funny business.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: The error originates from nlu-wcnlp, but it's traced to the project nlu-spacy, which contains the error.

Comment: The _other_ thing is that there's a flag that needs to be set in `setup.py` to ensure that your content is installed as separate files.

Comment: Re: your last comment -- please amend the question with details sufficient to make it clear (a stack trace, perhaps?)

Comment: What flag in the setup.py? I will check it.

Comment: It's `zip_safe=False` I was thinking of. And btw -- you've got `package_data` configured, right?

Comment: ...but if those are set incorrectly, the file won't _exist_. If it exists but your code is just having trouble finding it, then it's a matter of making the code resolve relative to the right location

Comment: ...and _that's_ the difference between `__file__ + '../../..<etc>'` (where you're making a potentially-invalid assumption about where your two modules are installed relative to each other) and `os.path.join(othermodule.__file__, 'wcnlp/configs/spacy_config.yml')` (where you're directly _asking_ where the other module is installed, and not assuming anything).

Comment: I've tried to edit the title to make it more descriptive of your problem. If I got some detail wrong, please feel free to edit further (but keeping the specificity if you can).

Comment: Yes, I have package_data in my setup.py.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `__file__` to search for data files associated with a package, you should always use a package relative to the `__file__` attribute for **a module associated with the package that provides the data file**. Do not try to use a relative path that spans the space between two packages, and thus assumes that it can correctly predict where those packages will be installed relative to each other.

So, this is unreliable (makes assumptions about installation locations that are not guaranteed to hold):

```
SPACEY_CONFIG_FILE = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 
                              '/../../../../site-packages/wcnlp/configs/spacy_config.yml'
```

...but this is okay:

```
import wcnlp
SPACEY_CONFIG_FILE = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(wcnlp.__file__),
                                  'configs/spacy_config.yml')
```